# MongoDB not adding default date for nested Schemas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to add a form result to an existing client in a collection and all form data variables being passed are added successfully, however, a default date variable is not being created and saved despite being in the schema.

Here is the schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const FormSchema = new Schema({
    formID: {
        type: String
    },
    formName: {
        type: String
    },
    date_completed: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    formData: {
        type: JSON
    }
});

const ClientSchema = new Schema({
    clientID: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    dob: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    formResults: {
        tags: [
            {
                type: FormSchema
            }
        ]
    }
});

module.exports = Client = mongoose.model('client', ClientSchema);
```

And here is the method posting the form results:

```
router.post('/:id', auth, (req, res) => {
    Client.update(
        { clientID: req.params.id },
        {
            $push: {
                formResults: {
                    $each: [
                        {
                            formID: req.body.formID,
                            formName: req.body.formName,
                            formData: req.body.formData
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    )
        .then(() => res.json({ success: true }))
        .catch(
            err => res.status(404).json({ success: false }) && console.log(err)
        );
});
```

I have tried forcing the date by passing `date_completed: Date.now` with the other form variables but this makes no difference. The results are still saved with no date variable listed. I have also tried dropping the collection and recreating it, this gave no changes. And I have checked the indexes for the collection, for which there is only _id and clientID.

Here is the data in saved in the database when executed and showing there is no date_completed: value.
[Stored Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts52g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, I wasn't able to find any reason why it was not working. I waited a few days and the issue fixed itself. I don't believe there was anything wrong with the code, I think the issue was to do with MongoDB Atlas not updating results and displaying the dates that were being created but again I have no idea why this would be the case.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance your code is correct and should have no problem as it complies with the documentation and tutorials of `mongoose`, you can test this code:

```
// Create Schema
const FormSchema = new Schema({
    formID: {
        type: String
    },
    formName: {
        type: String
    },
    date_completed: {
        type: Date,
        default: function() {
            if (!this.date_completed) {
                return Date.now();
            }
            return null;
        }
    },
    formData: {
        type: JSON
    }
});
```

or:

```
var minuteFromNow = function(){
    var timeObject = new Date();
    return timeObject;
};

// Create Schema
const FormSchema = new Schema({
    formID: {
        type: String
    },
    formName: {
        type: String
    },
    date_completed: {
        type: Date,
        default: minuteFromNow
    },
    formData: {
        type: JSON
    }
});
```

Let us also say this null is a valid value for a Date property, unless you specify required. Defaults only get set if the value is undefined, not if its falsy.

Comment: I tried each of these and neither worked. I also tried both of these and the original code with `required: true` and on new clients, again, none of these worked. I have also added a screenshot to the original post to show the data being saved if that helps.